# If Statement If A2 is Empty Dont Run Code - else run code if A2 has Data - Google Apps Script / GoogleSheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have tried to get this if statement to run as I am not yet experienced enough to know what I am doing wrong. (it runs perfectly if I manually run the script)

Expected result = if A2 has data - run the below code. if A2 is blank - dont run the code.

```
function IfStatement() {
var app = SpreadsheetApp;
var activeSheet = app.getActive().getActiveSheet();
var workingCell = activeSheet.getRange(2, 1).getValue();

if(workingCell === ""){
}

function kk() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('TOP UP NEEDED'), true);
sheet.getRange('D2').activate();
sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=QUERY({\'SKU & Qty\'!$A$3:$C},"SELECT * WHERE Col1 MATCHES \'" & 
JOIN("|",FILTER(A:A, NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)))) & "\' ")');
addCheckboxToI2();
}}

Hoping I was close !
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run the script of `function kk() {###}` when `workingCell` is not empty, how about this modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function IfStatement() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var workingCell = activeSheet.getRange(2, 1).getValue();
  if (workingCell === "") return;  // Modified

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('TOP UP NEEDED'), true);
  sheet.getRange('D2').activate();
  sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=QUERY({\'SKU & Qty\'!$A$3:$C},"SELECT * WHERE Col1 MATCHES \'" & JOIN("|",FILTER(A:A, NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)))) & "\' ")');
  addCheckboxToI2();
}
```

- `if(workingCell === ""){}` was modified to `if (workingCell === "") return;`.
- `function kk() {` was removed.

By this modification, when the value of `workingCell` is not empty, the below script of `if (workingCell === "") return;` is run. When the value of `workingCell` is empty, the script is finished at `if (workingCell === "") return;`.

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Tanaike - I was close, more learning to still do. Your Modification works as intended. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Tom Sawkins Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Sorry Tanaike - I then added a timed trigger so it would run automatically. Timer was set to 1 min to run(for testing). it actually runs the script and puts an #na at D2 ? should I trigger with onFormsubmit ?

Comment: @Tom Sawkins Thank you for replying. About your new question, I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do from `it actually runs the script and puts an #na at D2 ? should I trigger with onFormsubmit ?`. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your goal, can you post it as new question by including the detail information. By this, I would like to confirm it, and also it will help other users think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Tanaike - I have done as you requested and posted my question. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
function doSomething() {

var app = SpreadsheetApp;

var activeSheet = app.getActive().getActiveSheet();
var workingCell = activeSheet.getRange(2, 1).getValue();

var otherSheet = app.getActive().getSheetByName('TOP UP NEEDED');
var otherCell = otherSheet.getRange('D2');

var formula = '=QUERY({\'SKU & Qty\'!$A$3:$C},"SELECT * WHERE Col1 MATCHES \'" & JOIN("|",FILTER(A:A, NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)))) & "\' ")';

  if(workingCell == ""){

  }
  else{

  otherCell.setFormula(formula);

  }

//addCheckboxToI2();
//ReferenceError: 'addCheckboxToI2' is niet gedefinieerd. (regel x, bestand 'y')

}
```

I have some doubts about the formula but do not know enough of formula's to say something helpful about that.